# How exactly works the @ResponseStatus Spring annotation for RESTful application?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about how Spring handles **REST** requests.

I know that with REST the resources are exposed as name and that the actions on these resources are the HTTP methods, such as **GET**, **PUT**, **POST**,  and **DELETE**.

And I know that requests are handled by the use of `@RequestMapping` annotations over the method that handles the operation on the resource.

From what I have understood, both standard web applications and RESTful applications use some codes to communicate with their clients (the RESTful application have an expanded set of codes) that I think represent the status of the request (for example **200** is the request is a successful GET returning content, etc.).

Now the documentation shows the use of the `@ResponseStatus` annotation as in this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/orders", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) // 201
public void createOrder(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Order order = createOrder(request);
    // determine full URI for newly created Order based on request
    response.addHeader("Location",
    getLocationForChildResource(request, order.getId()));
}
```

So looking at the previous method I know that it handles **HttpRequest POST** requests towards the resource named **/orders** (using REST the resource is seen as an URL, is that correct?).

But what exactly does the annotation below do:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) // 201
```

I know that the **201** status code means that a **new resource was created on POST**.

And looking at the official documentation I can read:

> Marks a method or exception class with the status code and reason that
> should be returned. The status code is applied to the HTTP response
> when the handler method is invoked, or whenever said exception is
> thrown.

So what exactly it means? I think that as is done in the previous example it sets the 201 status that says that the resource is correctly created by the POST request. If this is correct I have 2 questions:

1. The resource is the **/orders** URI. So what is created? a file named **orders** (I think that this assertion is false) or what?
2. Where the 201 status is put?

Comment: I think before learning Spring, you should learn the basics of HTTP. Each HTTP response has a status. 200 means OK. 201 means "you asked to create something and I did it". In this case, as the method name indicates, an order has been created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

201 is an [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). It indicates that the

> request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created.

So if your server is returning such a status code, then the client understands that some (conceptual) resource was created. What that resource is is your responsibility, you're the server.

A status code is part of the [HTTP response status line.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)